# Invalid XML character Error - How to find the invalid character from a VARCHAR2 database column?

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

Oracle newbie here.

I am getting this error "Character reference "&#56256" is an invalid XML character" for XML data that is printed onto a report.
The XML data that is causing the issue is from a VARCHAR2 data column in the database.
I have filtered out the column and now I want to go through the records in order to find this invalid character is in which record and write an update statement replacing the invalid character with a valid one.
I am not sure how to do this.
Is there a regex I can write with a SELECT statement for this?
Can someone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Does `where your_column like unistr('%\dbc0%')` find the offending row(s)?

Comment: Hi Alex, no this doesn't fetch any results...

Answer (score 0):

To identify which entries have the character you want to eliminate you can search the column for the character

```
select colname 
  from tabname 
 where instr(colname,chr(56256)) > 0;
```

you can replace with an update statement:

```
update tablname
   set colname = replace(colname,chr(56256),'replacementstring')
 where instr(colname,chr(56256)) > 0;
```

Comment: Hi Niall, the select statement doesn't return any results... 
I took a backup of the column values as a separate table and tried to update that using SET text = REPLACE(text, CHR(56256)) , and then it said all rows were updated, instead of zero. I am puzzled now.

Comment: It would have updated all rows if you didn't use a where statement - even if that leaves the rows unchanged.  Try looking at one of the bad strings character by character using the ascii() function to get the exact character code of the bad character that is in your strings.

Comment: Hi Niall, 
still no results fetched... is there other alternatives I can do to resolve this?

Comment: Where you able to find the ascii code of the bad character using "Try looking at one of the bad strings character by character using the ascii() function to get the exact character code of the bad character that is in your strings." ?

Comment: Hi Niall,
yep. Tried ascii(), instr(), unistr().... no results.